# Centos7 "mount -a" "mount point /mnt/dev/ does not exist"

Tags: centos, mount

Adding the following line to the /etc/fstab and rebooting seems to work as expected, i.e. al of the files in the shared directory "DEV" are available and read-only.

*/etc/fstab*

```
//192.168.99.100/DEV /mnt/dev/ cifs _netdev,username=username,password=password,ro,uid=500,gid=1001 0 0
```

However, I am trying to mount this the machines provisioning and avoid rebooting, so I've tried doing a "mount -a" but get the following error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -a
mount: mount point /mnt/dev/ does not exist
```

How can I make this mount available without rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I guess that just adding an /etc/fstab entry automatically creates the mount directory at some point during the first reboot.  Soo.... in order to avoid rebooting, I apparently need to manually create the directory first

```
mkdir /mnt/dev
mount -a
```

(rejoice)